# Find closest neighboring point and list of neighbors within a given radius, coordinates lat-long

Tags: r, gis, geospatial

I am attempting to match/link 2 datasets, each of which have a lat lon. I'd like to produce the closest n matches by distance for each given coordinate in the first dataset. I am able to get the closest match but not sure how to expand this to get n number of matches.

The datasets look like this-
**table_1**

| id_1 | lat_1 | lon_ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 50.8613159 | 1.2483 |
| d7 | 50.8526967 | 1.2566349 |
| s2 | 50.8666 | 1.2433232 |

**table_2**

| id_2 | lat_2 | lon_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x2 | 50.8713562548622 | 1.24447448004003 |
| r1 | 50.8548464 | 1.2402125971721 |
| o9 | 50.87906755026 | 1.2453153747299 |

The code i've been using to determine the closest match has been finding the euclidean dist from the `RANN` package.

```
table_1[, c(3, 4)] <- as.data.frame(RANN::nn2(table_1[, c("lat_1", "lon_1")],
                                              table_2[, c("lat_2", "lon_2")], k=1))
```

which returns an index number and distance. Ideally, i'd like my output to look like-

For 3 closest matches :

| id_1 | lat_1 | lon_1 | index_no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 50.8613159 | 1.2483 | 3 |
| a1 | 50.8613159 | 1.2483 | 2 |
| a1 | 50.8613159 | 1.2483 | 1 |

Where the last column index_no provides the index number of the closest coordinates from table_2, and populate id_1 3 times to provide the 3 closest matches in any order by dist in km or m.

Comment: Did you try changing k to 3?

Answer (score 0):

Use `k=3` and `cbind` every row to `"dat1"` using `apply()`. Note that the data in which the neighbors are to be found should be put first (for illustration I extended your second data set by one line).

```
r <- RANN::nn2(dat1[, c("lat_1", "lon_1")], 
               dat2[, c("lat_2", "lon_2")], k=4)$nn.idx |>
  apply(1, cbind, dat1) |>
  do.call(what=rbind) |>
  {\(.) {names(.)[1] <- 'index_no';.[order(.$id), c(2:3, 1)]}}()  ## optional step, 
                                                                  ## sort and 
                                                                  ## rename cols

r
#   id_1    lat_1 index_no
# 1   a1 50.86132        2
# 4   a1 50.86132        4
# 7   a1 50.86132        1
# 2   d7 50.85270        1
# 5   d7 50.85270        2
# 8   d7 50.85270        2
# 3   s2 50.86660        4
# 6   s2 50.86660        1
# 9   s2 50.86660        3
```

**Note:** For the `|>` pipes you need an R version at least 4.1. If you are condemned to use an old R version, try:

```
do.call(apply(RANN::nn2(dat1[, c("lat_1", "lon_1")], 
                        dat2[, c("lat_2", "lon_2")], k = 4)$nn.idx, 
              1, cbind, dat1), what = rbind)
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat1 <- structure(list(id_1 = c("a1", "d7", "s2"), lat_1 = c(50.8613159, 
50.8526967, 50.8666), lon_1 = c(1.2483, 1.2566349, 1.2433232)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

dat2 <- structure(list(id_2 = c("x2", "r1", "o9", "xy"), lat_2 = c(50.8713562548622, 
50.8548464, 50.87906755026, 50.85), lon_2 = c(1.24447448004003, 
1.2402125971721, 1.2453153747299, 1.25)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: i'm sorry but what exactly is the $nn.idx |> portion of this mean? I think i understand the approach but i'm a bit confused by the code

Comment: @AamashHaroon It is the new base pipe, please see update.  Are you able to update your R to >= 4.1?